# Why url ends with ?_={timestamp} in load js script request?

Tags: javascript, c#, browser-cache

In view I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cm/customfield.scripting-helper.js")"></script>
```

But in Chrome Developer Console, tab Network I see this:

.../Scripts/cm/customfield.scripting-helper.js?_=1458129402165

How can I programmatically remove this substring? Or prevent it?

Comment: To nullify any local caching

Comment: There's a checkbox in the Network tab named 'Disable cache'. Uncheck it.

Comment: @Jai First comment explains what it does. OP asks how to CHANGE it. I don't see the problem.

Comment: How I can nullify any local caching?

Comment: Voting to reopen, the linked question explains why this is happening, but doesn't answer the question on how to change it.